# JDesktopPane occupies the entire JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a JDesktopPane `desktopPane` inside a JFrame. I want this desktoppane to occupy only a certain space so that the contents in the right of the JFrame is visible to the user. I tried using the method `setBounds(...)` and `setPreferredSize(..)` with `desktopPane` but could not acieve the desired result. The desktopPane occupies the entire frame and the unused space shows the background color as defined by `desktopPane.setBackground(..)`. Is there any way by which I can make the JDesktopPane occupy only the required space in a JFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, whose default (`CENTER`) position will want to occupy as much of the available space that is available.

`JDesktopPane` typically has a preferred size of `0x0`, which makes it fine to play with.

You could try other layout managers, but you will need to first overcome the issue of the default preferred size.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

The question is though, why?  A MDI typically wants to take the lion share of the screen real estate.